# Are "Men of Low Moral Fiber" and pirate leaders the same?

Tags: return-to-monkey-island

I started to play *Return to Monkey Island*, and when I was in the town of Mêlée, I met the Men of Low Moral Fiber. And the game even said, "These are the Men of Low Moral Fiber". But when I talked to them, Guybrush asked why they are not the pirate leaders anymore and why they have Captain Madison as the leader now.

But why? In the first game, *The Secret of Monkey Island*, these were totally different people. The Men of Low Moral Fiber were sitting in town and sold me the card, while the pirate leaders sat in the SCUMM-Bar.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [wiki](https://monkeyisland.fandom.com/wiki/Men_of_Low_Moral_Fiber#Biography):

> The trio are ex-pirates who quit through fear of LeChuck.

I don't believe this is explicitly explained in game, but the conversations do lead on to hint that they quit Pirating to enter into several (failed) business ideas. This then would probably lead to the name/hint of "Men Of Low Moral Fiber", rather than the title of "Pirates".

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a reference. The "Men of Low Moral Fibre" (a euphemism for "Pirates") were three specific pirates who appeared in exactly that spot in *The Secret of Monkey Island* (and elsewhere in *Monkey Island 2: LeChuck's Revenge*).

Thus when three different pirates are in the same place, both Guybrush and the player naturally mistake them for the same three as before, but soon learn who they actually are.

Even if you hadn't played the previous games, it still works, because they are clearly pirates, and the joke of the euphemism remains.